# implementing IDisposable for large MVP project in C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, dispose

I have an MVP project that has memory leaks (it's not a web project). The memory goes up each time when loading data from the database into a grid on a form. I tried investigating each object that is connected to that form with ANTS and .NET Memory profiler.

The objects connected to the form when opening / closing it are like this on the Instance Retention Graph:

> A -> B : object1 marked on the ->; (references)
>   B -> A : object2 marked on the ->; (referenced by)
>   where A, B are classes

Is it the next direction the right approach ?
1. To implement in the base classes the `IDisposable` pattern1 from [msdn.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) in each .cs module which doesn't have it implemented;

1. In  derived classes classes to implement pattern2 from msdn (the one which overrides `Dispose` method)
2. Put some function that clears objects / other references (object.property, object.other_field) in the "managed resources" section from the `Dispose` Method
3. Force object to null or object.Dispose() exactly when the object is not longer used in that .cs (do this for each .cs? or is there another way)

How can I force all these methods and the GC to execute let's say at the closing of the form explicitly?

If I get rid of the objects from the specific .cs's will it be enough?

Thanks

Comment: `Dispose()` is primarily about resource management, not about memory leaks. So No, this is not the right direction. Look at how you manage ownership (lifetime of references).

Comment: How much data are you loading into this grid on the form?

Comment: ok, yes, i know I should investigate other elements as well`@Henk Holterman`; I wanted to free references to the form sa that the GC will finally be able to clean up memory. I also watched a lot of large objects that are promoted to gen2 but they are necessary for the program to work. I also watched LOH and only about 10mb are used by objects. Fragmentation is sometimes common and doesn't always tell the exact problem. `@Henk Holterman`

Comment: @Mpn You can possibly show 2gb of data on the screen.

Comment: it comes from the DB with the use of Telerik mapping @Magnus

Comment: @MPN You need to use paging on the grid to only get the data displayed from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

`IDisposable` is not about Garbage Collecting or memory management, or at least not *directly*. What MS says about it:

*The primary use of this interface is to release **unmanaged** resources. The garbage collector automatically releases the memory allocated to a managed object when that object is no longer used.*

If your object do not contain unmanaged resources, you should not implement `IDisposable`, otherwise it would give other coders the impression that it does.

If you want to release managed resources, you simply have to break the link between the main program reference tree and the resources. In this case, if you don't need the form any more, it could be a very simple point to release.

```
MyForm = null;
```

Or if you want to release only resources inside the form, you could break their references in a callback inside the form.

```
protected void OnFormClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyVeryFatObjectList = new List<object>();
}
```

If for some reason you want to explicitly call the garbage collector:

```
System.GC.Collect();
```

However, note that is it not recommended to do so. The GC is generally intelligent enough to do its job properly if you do yours correctly.

Comment: so I just >foreach every object and set them to null? and all objects in contact with the database? this is how to break their references? @LightStriker

Comment: @MPN: Why foreach? Why not simply re-init the list/table/array? `MyList = new List<MyObjectType>();` ? As long as you break the chain of reference somewhere, any objects and their references down the chain will be collected.

Comment: i have objects from other forms that reffer this form; i should do this in those other forms as well, no? i know these objects from the profiler. @LightStriker

Comment: You should have, most likely, a choke point somewhere; a place where the bulk of your data exist, referenced in a single point. For example, those objects that cost a lot of memory, the are probably referenced in a List or a Table of some kind, right? Unless you're telling me your data is referenced at multiple places in your code?

Comment: so to free unmanaged resources I have to find and release the objects that connect with the database and use `using` form files (or MemoryStream, FileStream), right? @LightStriker

Comment: The data (which should be cached) is loaded in the form from a DB with the use of Stored procedures. At the reopening of the same form the memory still goes up, so the program duplicates objects that are used to load the form again...these are the objects that I tried to put them to null exactly after use. the problem is that they are used in other forms also, so THERE I should put them to null also. @LightStriker

Comment: @MPN; Well, what you want is to break your reference towards that stored data. If you somehow share that data upon request with other forms or other object, that could be a good design flaws. In my opinion, when you request data from a DB, you should "store" it at a single place and have other object/form use that storage and not have their own reference towards it. So when you want to flush it for a new set of data, you do it at a single place and have some guaranty that memory won't increased for no reason.

Comment: i'll look into it to see if other objects reffer to the DB directly. If so, this is bad, right? @LightStriker

Comment: @MPN; Multiple object referencing a DB is not a problem. The problem is when you retrieve data from that DB. How is it retrieved and stored in memory for your objects to use? Who retrieve it and how does it handle its disposition?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28216/discussion-between-mpn-and-lightstriker)

Comment: can it be from Telerik data binding to the gridview? @LightStriker

Comment: the data is dynamically taken from db with stored procedures and put DIRECTLY in the form, after some filters are applied. A good idea is that it should be stored intermediately in some DataTable, but then again every filter is different, of course, and I believe you can't store the whole result in some in-memory table, can I? @LightStriker

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your A references B, B references A statement above I'm guessing that you have a circular object reference which is preventing garbage collection from cleaning up your references.

Garbage collection runs from time to time and cleans up memory used by objects that are no longer referenced. If two objects reference each other then they won't be cleaned up.

You can remove a reference simply buy changing it's value to null.

Another way that this kind of thing can happen, especially in a winforms app is via event handlers, so unhook any event handlers you've added once you've finished with them.

Implementing the IDisposable interface provides you with a nice method where you can put all of your clean up code and informs users of your class that cleanup is required. It's still up to you to make sure that the dispose method is called, either directly or via a using statement.

Also, if you want to hold a reference to an object in a loose kind of way that won't prevent it being garbage collected you can use a [WeakReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx), but this is not going to be needed most of the time.